# How can I return a node even when its related objects aren't found?

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-aura

I am trying to fetch a parent node and its related nodes by id. It works fine but when I try to filter the related nodes by certain criteria the parent node itself is not returned when the related nodes do not pass the given criteria or filters

```
MATCH (obj{CId:"AT11"})
OPTIONAL MATCH (obj)-[r]->(related)
WHERE related.Created >= "2024-03-03" AND related.Created <= "2024-03-06" 
WITH obj,related
WHERE related.CId CONTAINS 'AT' 
RETURN obj, related
```

I expect obj to be returned even if related is null. In my case both return null even though obj exists

I tried removing some of the filters and I realized when using only one where clause works fine but using multiple where clause seems to be the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To always return `obj`, all the `related` filtering should be done in the `WHERE` clause of the `OPTIONAL MATCH`:

```
MATCH (obj {CId:"AT11"})
OPTIONAL MATCH (obj)-->(related)
WHERE "2024-03-03" <= related.Created <= "2024-03-06" AND related.CId CONTAINS 'AT'
RETURN obj, related
```

Note: this query also uses [chained comparison](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/operators/#cypher-operations-chaining) for the `Created` date.

##### Optional filtering

If you pass [parameters](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/parameters/) for the `obj` CId (`$obj_cid`) and the `related` filtering (`$date_range` and `$rel_cid_substr`), and the filtering parameters are optional (that is, can have `NULL` values), you can use the following:

```
MATCH (obj)
WHERE obj.CId = $obj_cid
OPTIONAL MATCH (obj)-->(related)
WHERE
  ($date_range IS NULL OR $date_range.start <= related.Created <= $date_range.max) AND
  ($rel_cid_substr IS NULL OR related.CId CONTAINS $rel_cid_substr)
RETURN obj, related
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply .This is fine however there will be situations where the client won’t pass the filter or the start date and end date. I’m receiving them as query Params. How do I make it work dynamically. It’s for this reason I separated the where clauses to use if statements to not apply the where clause when the query param isn’t passed

Comment: I added an `Optional filtering` section to my answer.

Comment: Alright then .I will test it out and vote your answer.